# Django NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a little django "board" app for my classmates.
But I'm getting this error which I can't find a way around.
I presume it has to be something to do with template rendering, but I don't know what the problems is. It was working fine until I made some modifications to the views & template below. Even after when I undid all the changes I made, it stopped working and returned the same error.

Error

```
NoReverseMatch at /board/2/
Reverse for 'read_article' with arguments '('', 10)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['board/(?P<board_id>\\d+)/(?P<article_id>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.101:8000/board/2/
Django Version: 1.7.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'read_article' with arguments '('', 10)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['board/(?P<board_id>\\d+)/(?P<article_id>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468
Python Executable:  /home/web/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.2
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    boards = Board.objects.order_by("title")
    dashboards = []
    try:
        if request.session["error"]:
            error_message = request.session["error"]
            del request.session["error"]
    except KeyError:
        error_message = None

    for board in boards:
        articles = board.article_set.order_by("-written_date")[:5]
        dashboard_item = {
            "board" : board,
            "articles" : articles,
        }
        dashboards.append(dashboard_item)

    context = {
        "boards" : Board.objects.all(),
        "dashboards" : dashboards,
        "error_message" : error_message,
    }

    return render(request, "index.html", context)


def read_board(request, board_id):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, id=board_id)
    article_list = board.article_set.order_by("-written_date")
    paginator = Paginator(article_list, 5)
    page = request.GET.get("page")

    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "articles" : articles,
        "pages" : paginator.page_range
    }

    return render(request, "board.html", context)


def read_article(request, board_id, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    reply_list = article.reply_set.order_by("written_date")
    try:
        if request.session["error"]:
            error_message = request.session["error"]
            del request.session["error"]
    except KeyError:
        error_message = None
    context = {
        "boards" : Board.objects.all(),
        "board_id" : board_id,
        "article" : article,
        "replies" : reply_list,
        "error_message" : error_message,
    }   

    return render(request, "article.html", context)
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'board.views.index', name = 'index'),
    url(r'^board/(?P<board_id>\d+)/$', 'board.views.read_board', name = 'board'),
    url(r'^board/(?P<board_id>\d+)/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'board.views.read_article', name = 'read_article'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template

```
{% include "header.html" %}
{% include "navbar.html" %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>{{ board.title }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-center">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">글번호</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5">글제목</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">작성자</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">작성시간</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if articles %}
            {% for article in articles %}
            <a href="{% url 'read_article' board.id article.id %}" class="list-group-item">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">{{ article.id }}</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-5">{{ article.title }}</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">{{ article.user.first_name }} {{ article.user.last_name }}</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">{{ article.written_date }}</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div class="list-group-item text-center">작성된 글이 없습니다</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'new_article' board.id %}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">새글쓰기</a>
    {% include "paginator.html" %}
</div>
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

Comment: @e4c5 can you specify where in code, I have \\d+? I can't find it.

Comment: sorry my bad, I looked at your error message and not the urls.py and quite forgot that the error message might convert \ into \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback I find that the board.id you provide in url tag in the template is empty, and in fact, you haven't specified it in your context.

Comment: Which views.py function should I change and how?

Comment: which view are you requesting ? i guest it may be      the read_board function. specify a board variable in the context

Comment: Found it. Thanks. I solved the problem by adding "board" : board, in context.

Comment: learn to get information from the traceback, it is important for you to solve problems.